# How to get app url?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, app

I'm creating a javascript app for sharepoint, and I need to get the url of this app. The same url that is in content of site.

I need another solution because when i try to simply reload the page with javascript, the browser cache return old variables populated and I get error in my communication with lists.

I want something like this:

```
location.href = context.thisAppUrl;
```

Comment: Isn't it available in the query string?

Comment: Now I saw, yes it is. I'll try to catch him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function manageQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
    document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}

var hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
```

Answer (score 2):

With "_spPageContextInfo" you can get all properties of app.

If you want only url of APP :

```
var AppWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
```

this code is the same of appweburl in query parameter.

But to get SPHostUrl try the method getQueryStringParameter(valueString)

```
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));    

function getQueryStringParameter(value) {


    var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');

    var strParams = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {

        var singleParam = params[i].split('=');

        if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey)

            return decodeURIComponent(singleParam[1]);

    }

}
```

Hope this help.